# How to draw a rectangle in Compact Edtion?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a windows mobile phone.

1. Draw the rectangle
2. Fill the rectangle with a color
3. Draw it on to the phone.
4. Give it a event handler that when a user clicks something happens.

I am unsure how do steps 2, 3 and 4. I see that there is a drawing class called rectangle but I don't know how to get it on the form.

I then don't know how I could give it a event handler. I am planning to dynamically make like 12 of these so I have to somehow tell which one is clicked and the color it contains in it.

Thanks

Edit so far I have this but I don't see it on my form.

```
 Graphics surface = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle test = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
    surface.DrawRectangle(pen, test);
```

Comment: ONLY use .CreateGraphics() to get a graphics object to measure strings. Never use it for drawing. Also you'll want to dispose your GDI objects once you are done with them. To simplify this you can shove them in a using block: using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f)){ /* code that uses the pen in here */}

Comment: Oh and if you're new to GDI+ I recommend reading this: http://www.bobpowell.net/faqmain.htm it is Full Framework specific but a lot of the same lessons apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a colored button. I think the easiest way to do this is to inherit from Control and override its Paint event.

```
public class ColoredButton : Control {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, Width-1, Height-1);
    }
}
```

Now just hook into the native control [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event.

Or if you want fancier controls, take a look at this library

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/uiframework